# How or where do music lyric sites get their data?

Tags: web, web-scraping

There are tonnes of music lyric sites out there. A while back, I was looking at some lyrics for a band I am in to. And it made me think, "How does this site obtain all these lyrics and how can I get my hands on something like this?" Could not find much back then, so I decided to write a program that would basically parsed a site for the bands information and lyrics and placed the data in a database that I created.

But I am still wondering how these sites get their data? My way is not very efficient, very site specific, and if the site changes its' script structure, I have to change my parsing program. There must be a simpler way.

Anyone's thoughts are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess at either JSON or XML files. To 'get your hands on it' - there are various ways and means of downloading data from a web site.  wget is one means, not that I condone it but it's hardly a secret

Answer (score 0):

Most of the website get their lyrics from users. Musixmatch for example, they allow user to create their lyric if the lyric do not exist in their database. When then user create a lyric, it would probably be automatically saved into musixmatch's database. There are tons of lyric websites allowing users to upload lyrics.

Another way websites get their data is through data mining, just like you said, writing a parser/scraper to go through someone else's website.